# I dont think i am using kotlin JS coroutines correctly

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I am using the ktor client to make rest calls.  Here is my call to the server

```kotlin
suspend fun fetchCustomerSummary(id: Int)  : Deferred<CustomerPDSummaryDTO> {
    val deffered: Deferred<CustomerPDSummaryDTO> = GlobalScope.async{jsonClient.post<CustomerPDSummaryDTO>("http://localhost:8080/customerSummary"){
        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
        body = GenericIntEQ(theInt = id)
    }}
    return deffered
}
```

Here is how i call that code and use the value returned

```kotlin
GlobalScope.launch {
    setCustomer("")
    val firstRequest = PredictService.fetchCustomerSummary(it.id)
    val result = firstRequest.await()
    props.importReq(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a single scope and call coroutines from it to make the [structural concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#structured-concurrency) work. Here is an example:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val scope = MainScope()
    scope.launch {
        val client = HttpClient {
            install(JsonFeature) {
                serializer = KotlinxSerializer(kotlinx.serialization.json.Json {
                    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                })
            }
        }

        launch {
            println(client.getOrigin())
        }

        val zen = async {
            client.getZen()
        }.await()

        println(zen)
    }
}

suspend fun HttpClient.getOrigin(): String {
    val response = post<BinResponse>("https://httpbin.org/post") {
        body = "123"
    }
    return response.origin
}

suspend fun HttpClient.getZen(): String {
    return get("https://api.github.com/zen")
}

@Serializable
data class BinResponse(val origin: String)
```